# How to use imported text in a variable in powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell, windows-event-log

I want an automatic AD unlock with some users.

I use this to import the info in a text file

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -ComputerName COMP -InstanceId 4740 -Newest 1 |
    Format-List >> $log
```

Then I use this

```
If ((Get-Content $log) -match $name )
{
    Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $Account_Name
}
```

Now the `$Account_Name` has to be the same as the username, which is listed in the first command (export eventlog). How can I do this?  Of course the username would be different each time, so I am wondering how I do this. Making an automatic unlock on some users would help me big time!

Something like %USERNAME% in a batch file.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Couldn't you just configure Active Directory to do this for you?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this approach it would probably make more sense to use Search-ADAccount cmdlet to look for locked accounts and just pipe any account that is on your list:

```
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut | 
    where { $ListOfUsersToUnlock -contains $_.Name } | 
    Unlock-ADAccount
```

You make it harder by parse&pray style of work (object -> text -> parsing -> object).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!

I run this now:

$log = "c:\powershell\test.log"
$name = "PC-test"

$ListOfUsersToUnlock = "cursus1"



Get-EventLog -LogName Security -ComputerName DC -InstanceId 4740 -Newest 1 | Format-List >> $log


If ((Get-Content $log) -match $name )


{

Seach-ADAccount -LockedOut | 
    where { $ListOfUsersToUnlock -contains $_.Name } | 
    Unlock-ADAccount

}

Comment: And i am getting this error now:

The term 'Seach-ADAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:36 char:16
+ Seach-ADAccount <<<<  -LockedOut | 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Seach-ADAccount:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Sorry I am a sort of newbie in powershell, but who do I do wrong?

Comment: Adding "Import-Module activedirectory" would not help by the way

Comment: Typo... ;) Should be: Search-ADAccount... Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

BartekB's answer is definitely a good answer to the original question being asked.  But having to constantly poll AD for locked accounts just to selectively unlock a subset if they happen to be locked seems like a really bad solution for the root problem.

At the end of the day, it sounds like you want to have a subset of your users who can't have their passwords locked out.  So why not just use [Fine-Grained Password Policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770394%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on that subset of users to prevent them from getting locked out in the first place?  No script is needed and there's no polling AD.  Just create your password settings object (PSO) that removes the lockout settings and target it at a group that contains the users you don't want locked out.